# Opening process with php and keeping it open between requests

Tags: java, php, terminal, xmlhttprequest

I have a computational terminal program that I need to interact with using a php webpage. I can do this in JAVA using getRuntime().exec(...) and then creating pipes that read from and write to the process, and the process will exist between requests. But I am not sure if it can be done with PHP as I dont think proc_open keeps the process alive during requests?

Here is the flow of the webpage I am creating. First the user will enter a command on the webpage, which will be fed to a the terminal program that performs the computation and then the answer is returned to the user. I will use AJAX for the request so that the answer is returned without refreshing the page.

Now my issue is that I need to interact with the same process on the next request rather than start a new one. This is because the terminal program has state. That is I can set variables in it like this - `X = 5;`

So on my first AJAX call to the program I pass

`X = 5;`

and the output from the program that is returned to the user's browser is -

`X = 5`

Then on my next AJAX request I pass

`Y = X + 5;`

and then the program should output

`Y = 10`

which gets passed back to the users browser.

But it is my understanding the the proc_open function does not maintain state between requests. I understand that the process is closed when the server responds to the user's request. Is this correct? And if so is there any way to do what I need to do using PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to look into [`$_SESSION`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)s. Since PHP doesn't have a concept of maintaining state sessions, this is how you can pass information from request to request.

Comment: Yes but it is not an option for me to create a new process on each request. I have to use the same process that is created initially. I am of the understanding that that proc_open opens a process for the the request and then that process is closed when the request ends?

Answer (score 2):

Use PHP sessions. See here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Basically, the server will issue a cookie identifier to the browser, and create an object variable `$_SESSION` that can hold anything you want. Each time the browser shows the cookie to the server, the server will retrieve the `$_SESSION` variable for that session, so your PHP script can get to it.

Answer (score 1):

If just storing the values using the concept of a session isn't enough, and this terminal program really does need to continue running:

Write a daemon program(in php or java or whatever you like). This program should listen on a local socket for connections, and will maintain an instance of your terminal program for each client. Your php scripts would just connect on the local sockets to this daemon program, send an id to identify which terminal instance is being continued, and then you can send commands and get responses, and the daemon just acts as a proxy/manager of the terminal instances.